# Is there any way to model an equivalent impedance value for an opamp? (not talking about input or output impedance, want a single value impedance)

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am trying to analyse the following circuit, and it has an opamp(TLV9002) in the feedback loop of opamp TLV07. It would be helpful if I can approximate the TLV9002 opamp as an impedance parallel to the 100nF capacitor. Is there an approximate value of impedance the opamp can be replaced with?

[image]

Comment: What about the grounding of the R3-R4 and R1-R2 divider? This is important for the gain of the feedback path.

Comment: *Is there an approximate value of impedance the opamp can be replaced with?* No because the opamp does not behave as an impedance. You can approximate (model) an opamp as a voltage controlled voltage source though.

Comment: @LvW it is not grounded. It is a difference amplifier so a voltage source is connected to them both and it will amplify the difference between them. There are no issues with the working of the circuit, just want to analyse the working.

Comment: The opamp TLV07 has no external input (to be procesed). Therefore, I think that it is the other opamp (TLV9002S) which acts as a main amplifier with TLV07 in the feedback loop. Do you agree? Of course, the main amp cannot be replaced by any passive part.

Comment: XY problem. Model it as an integrator.